# Random Enum returns null

Tags: java, random, enums

Hello i am trying to get random ENUM, but it returns null, someone can help me what's wrong in my code ? I was trying to repair it alone but i give up.

```
public class LotteryMachine {
    protected enum Sings {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
}

    private static final List<Sings> SINGS_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(Sings.values()));
    private static final int SIZE = SINGS_LIST.size();
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    Sings randomSing() {
        return SINGS_LIST.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));

    }
}


public class Game {

    private LotteryMachine lotteryMachine = new LotteryMachine();

    private LotteryMachine.Sings singOne;
    private LotteryMachine.Sings singTwo;
    private LotteryMachine.Sings singThree;

    private void Lottery(){
        this.singOne = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
        this.singTwo = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
        this.singThree = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
    }

    public void viewLottery(){
        System.out.print(singOne + " " + singTwo + " " + singThree);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried, I don't have null

Comment: Did you called `Lottery();` before calling `viewLottery()`? Can you please show the code from where you are calling `viewLottery`

Comment: Please give the code on How you use all of this

Comment: @azro How it is mandatory? Lottery() is just a method, not the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be here

```
private void Lottery(){
    this.singOne = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
    this.singTwo = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
    this.singThree = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
}
```

This is not a constructor; instead it's a private method called `Lottery()` and not used by the `Game` class. Because the method is never called, all of the `singX` fields are left uninitialized (i.e. null). Things should work after you move the initialization logic from said method to the field declarations like this

```
private LotteryMachine.Sings singOne = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
private LotteryMachine.Sings singTwo = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
private LotteryMachine.Sings singThree = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
```

or alternatively declare the constructor of the `Game` class as follows:

```
public Game() {
    this.singOne = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
    this.singTwo = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
    this.singThree = lotteryMachine.randomSing();
}
```